# Custom partition specification while consuming message

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka

I have a topic 'sampleTopic' with 6 partitions and have 3 consumers. I want the consumer1 to consume from partition 1 & 3, the consumer2 to consume from partition 2 & 5, and consumer3 to consume from partition 4 & 6. I tried to implement a custom partition strategy using `assign()`, but am not getting the result as expected.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to use assign. In general, that is an anti-pattern in Kafka consumers. Running 3 consumers in the same consumer group (using subscribe) should evenly distribute 2 partitions to each instance from a topic of 6 partitions.

When one consumer instance terminates, the partitions will rebalance to 3 partitions to each

---

Use different topics if you must consume and *process* specific subsets of data.